# How handle Business Layer error localization when there are separate UI and API front ends?

Tags: c#, exception, localization

My application has both a UI (ASP.Net) and a WebServices API (WCF) front end that both invoke a single business layer. We use a custom Exception type to communicate errors from the business layer that are safe to display to end users. For example if a user attempts to perform an action that is beyond their credentials the business layer would throw a new FriendlyException("You do not have permission"). The UI layer then handles this exception and shows this message to the end user. If the API made this call then inside the FaultException data would be the "You do not have permission" message.

The problem we have now is we need to start localizing all these messages. The current thinking is to have the BusinessLayer throw static strings ("NO_PERMISSION_ERROR") that would be used by the UI and API handlers to find localized string in their respective resouce files. The only downside to this is our API localization and the UI en-US localization are essentially the same and duplicated. Can we avoid this by using some other pattern or are we on the right track?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely on the right track. You need some identifier (a static string) that need to be resolved to translated message at runtime.

Theoretically you could add something like "getLocalizedMessage(CultureInfo ci)" to your custom exception class, but this doesn't work very well with distributed applications.

Just stick to what you come up already. L10n sometimes requires some redundancy but you can't help it.